# When using rasterize=True with datashader, how do I get transparency where count=0 to see the underlying tile?

Tags: tiles, holoviews, datashader, hvplot, geoviews

Currently, when I do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas

df = pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()
plot = df.hvplot.points('A', 'B', tiles=True, rasterize=True, geo=True,
                        aggregator='count')
```

I can't see the underlying tile source.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the underlying tile source philippjfr suggested setting the color bar limits slightly higher than 0 and set the min clipping_colors to transparent:

```
plot = plot.redim.range(**{'Count': (0.25, 1)})
plot = plot.opts('Image', clipping_colors={'min': 'transparent'})
```

Now the underlying tile source is viewable.

[image]

Full Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas

df = pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()
plot = df.hvplot.points('A', 'B', tiles=True, rasterize=True, geo=True,
                        aggregator='count')

plot = plot.redim.range(**{'Count': (0.25, 1)})
plot = plot.opts('Image', clipping_colors={'min': 'transparent'})
plot
```